# Prove that probability distribution function is continuous at a point

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $X$ be a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Show that $F_X(x)$ is continuous at $x = x_0$ if and only if $\mathbb{P}(X = x_0)= 0.$

$\underline{\mathrm{Proof}}$:

($\rightarrow$ direction)

Suppose $F_X$ is continuous at $x = x_0$. Then,

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(X = x_0) &=&F_X(x_0) - \lim_{y \rightarrow x_0^{-}} F_X(y), \\
&=& F_X(x_0) - F_X(x_0), \hspace{1cm} (\mathrm{since\ } F_X \mathrm{\ is\ continuous\ at\ } x=x_0), \\
&=& 0,
\end{eqnarray}

as required.

($\leftarrow$ direction)

Suppose $\mathbb{P}(X = x_0) = 0$. Then,

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(X = x_0) &=& F_X(x_0) - \lim_{y \rightarrow x_0^{-}} F_X(y) \\
\implies \lim_{y \rightarrow x_0^{-}} F_X(y) &=& F_X(x_0)\hspace{1cm} (\mathrm{since\ } \mathbb{P}(X = x_0) = 0).
\end{eqnarray}

This means that $F_X$ is left continuous $x_0$. Since $F_X$ is right continuous for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ it is right-continuous at $x = x_0$. Thus $F_X$ is continuous at $x = x_0$. $\square$

Is this proof okay?

Comment: seems good to me :)

Comment: OK, thanks very much!